# htmlRenderer.PDFSharp not converting labels

Tags: html, pdfsharp, xhtmlrenderer

I am trying to get familiar with [htmlRenderer.pdfsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp) and have come across an issue that I am trying to figure out.  It is not rendering the following HTML:

```
<td><label for=\"Date\">Date</label></td>
```

The code I am using to generate the PDF is from one of their examples but it is as follows:

```
PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PageSize.Letter);
```

The rest of the HTML is populating just fine and am not sure where to go from here with the HTML Renderer.  Anyone else ran into this issue and have a fix?

Edit: I removed calling it PDFSharp's html render and linked to the nuget package I am using for htmlRender.pdfsharp.

Comment: PDFsharp does not have a HTML renderer. You are using a third-party add-on that uses PDFsharp.

Comment: Updated the post to link what I am using.